# DOM, Selectors API tags (querySelectorAll() et al)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

If you're a Web developer, you may have heard of the `querySelectorAll()` DOM method, which accepts a selector list and returns matching elements where applicable. It's supported in IE8 and later, so it enjoys pretty widespread use.

Most developers know this API by the methods `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()`, but they are actually defined in a standard known as the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api). Level 2 of this API was in development for a while before being merged into [DOM level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom) (see the [note](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2)), but it will introduce more methods in addition to the aforementioned two.

Currently there are two tags that are being used to refer to these methods: [queryselectorall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryselectorall) and [selectors-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectors-api) (surprisingly, [queryselector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryselector) does not exist). I have been retagging questions changing the former to the latter for a while, but now that the Selectors API is being consolidated into DOM4, I'm not entirely sure what tag should be used going forward.

We generally try not to use tags that refer to specific methods, especially when there are many others related to it, so [queryselectorall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryselectorall) should probably go or we'll have a bunch of these method tags. But what should be used in its place?

- [selectors-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selectors-api) (I [suggested a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectors-api/synonyms) some time ago but it has not received any votes)
- [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom)
- [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom) [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors)

Or is it safe to make other method tags synonyms of [queryselectorall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryselectorall) and just go with that?

Comment: I was about to say that a tag for `queryselectorall` sounded just as useless as having a tag for `tostring`, but then I realized... we do. Anyway, I'd go for `selectors-api` and then make an alias for `css-selectors`. To me, using `dom` sounds wrong as that's a much wider topic.

Comment: @ivarni: Can you clarify what you mean by an alias for css-selectors?

Comment: That when someone tries to tag with `css-selectors` it gets mapped to `selectors-api`. Synonym. The word my brain was trying to use was synonym. I'm not sure why my fingers didn't listen. Sorry. It's 7 am here :)

Comment: @ivarni: Ah. css-selectors refers to the selector language, selectors-api is just one of several technologies and APIs that uses selectors to query elements, much like jQuery. A synonym wouldn't be appropriate in this case.